# OpenERP : What will be the name of newly created user when this command is executed?

Tags: linux

```
sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/openerp --group openerp
```

What will be the name of newly created user when above command is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is no OpenERP command. This is a command for creating a user in Linux.
2. I guess it won't run, because there is no user name given.

This creates a user `openerp`:

```
sudo adduser --system --home=/opt/openerp --group openerp openerp
```

Answer (score 0):

this will create openerp user for openerp